# How can i use raw_input and string formatting % or %d python

Tags: python, string, raw-input

i have variable var, and it is changeable
how can i use raw_input and inside `raw_input` make a question and use this variable
i.e.

```
z = raw_input("Is your age %d') %(var)
```

but this don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
z = raw_input("Is your age %d" %(var,) )
```

Answer (score 1):

With `raw_input`, %var should also lie within the parentheses. i.e:

```
z = raw_input("Is your age %d" % var)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the cleanest way is to use `format`:

```
z = raw_input("Is your age {0}?".format(var))
```

Comment: I think this is the best way since it is standart in Python 3 and can be used under Python 3 and Python 2.